# MongoDB querydsl: query two fields on the same objects with and operator

Tags: json, spring, mongodb, querydsl

I have the following query:

```
BooleanExpression bex = qEntity.contacts.any().someField.eq(param1).and(qEntity.contacts.any().otherField.eq(param2));
```

But it's wrong for my purposes. I need to match someField and otherField on the same contacts object. The query above returns true, even if each field is matched on a different contacts object.

`Entity` has this structure:

```
{
    "contacts": [
            {
                "someField": "a",
                "otherField": "b"
            },
            {
                "someField": "c",
                "otherField": "d"
            }
    ]
}
```

And I need to find the contacts object where both someField and otherField match,

How do I do this?

Comment: Is contacts a nested documents or an array of documents?

Comment: it's an array of documents., I corrected it. Thanks!